# Printing geometric sequence table using 2D array and nested loops

Tags: java, arrays, nested-loops

I'm new to programming and I need help. So, my program needs to print a geometric sequence in a table format using 2D array. But I'm also very aware that I'm missing lines of code to make the desired output (and I don't know what to add):

```
      1 2  4  8 16 32 64 128 256 512
      2 4  8 16 32 64...
      4 8 16...
      8... 
     16...
     32...    
     64... 
    128...
    256...
    512...
```

Here's what I got so far:

```
    int [][] array = new int[10][10];
    array[0][0] = 1;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
        for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            array[i][j] = (i+i) + (j+j);
        }   
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
        for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        } 
    System.out.println();   
    }
```

I already searched some related programs and questions but neither of them helped me. Anyway, if someone responds, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to populate the array would be to use separate loop variables for rows and columns, with each value being doubled on each iteration.

The row value starts at 1, and the column value starts at the current row value.

```
int n = 10;
int [][] array = new int[n][n];
for(int i=0,r=1; i<n; i++,r*=2)
  for(int j=0,c=r; j<n; j++,c*=2)
    array[i][j] = c;
```

Or you could exploit the symmetry of the table, noting that it's reflected across the diagonal, to do a little less work:

```
for(int i=0,r=1; i<n; i++,r*=4)
    for(int j=i,c=r; j<n; j++,c*=2)
        array[i][j] = array[j][i] = c;
```

Java doesn't have an exponent operator (you can use `Math.pow`) but if we just want to raise a number to some power of 2 we can use use the left shift operator (<<), since each left shift the argument.

```
int [][] array = new int[n][n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j=i; j<n; j++)
        array[i][j] = array[j][i] = 1 << (i+j);
```

In terms of printing and formatting, it would be nice if we could calculate how wide the largest value is going to be. If we're computing `n` terms the largest value is going to be `4^(n-1)`, i.e. 4 raised to the power of `n-1`. We can calculate how many digits this value has using the `log10` function.

```
int maxDigits = 1 + (int)Math.log10(Math.pow(4, n-1));
```

Note that we need to add 1 to the value returned. We can then use this to build a format string that will print our numbers right-justified and padded to take up the required width.

```
String fmt = "%" + (1 + maxDigits) + "d";
```

Note that we again add 1 to account for the required space.

We can now print the table using the `System.out.format` method:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
  {
    System.out.format(fmt, array[i][j]);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
  1      2      4      8     16     32     64    128    256    512
  2      4      8     16     32     64    128    256    512   1024
  4      8     16     32     64    128    256    512   1024   2048
  8     16     32     64    128    256    512   1024   2048   4096
 16     32     64    128    256    512   1024   2048   4096   8192
 32     64    128    256    512   1024   2048   4096   8192  16384
 64    128    256    512   1024   2048   4096   8192  16384  32768
128    256    512   1024   2048   4096   8192  16384  32768  65536
256    512   1024   2048   4096   8192  16384  32768  65536 131072
512   1024   2048   4096   8192  16384  32768  65536 131072 262144
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, sir! But out of my curiosity, I want to know if there's a difference between `Math.pow()` and just a simple exponential operator which is this one, `**` since I tried the latter and just gave me errors.

Comment: Java doesn't have an exponent operator, but if you want to raise an argument to some power of two, as you do here, you can use the left shift operator (<<). I've updated the answer with this option.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be with (in first loop):

```
array[i][j] = (int)Math.pow(2,i)*(int)Math.pow(2,j);
```

Base start with `1` and is `2 at power i` on each line. After just multiply with `2 at corresponding power`(j, per line elements).

`[0_i,0_j]=base*next=2^0*2^0=1*1`

`[1,2]=2^1*2^2=2*4=8`, etc

Comment: If use basic algebra, expression can be reduced to `(int)Math.pow(2,i+j)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! But one follow-up question though, does format specifiers like `%d` works on this to align the content? Or do I have to change that?

Comment: Try with `System.out.format("%7d",array[i][j]);` (or `%-7d` from left) and maybe want to consider the answer.

Comment: It gave me console errors. But I already figured it out. Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: If adjust properly  you will not have any errors !  ... but anyway if were helpful then use what ever you needed.

Comment: One last question and just out of my curiosity, I want to know if there's a difference between `Math.pow()` and just a simple exponential operator which is this one, `**` since I tried the latter and just gave me errors.

Comment: If you try `**` what is the output and maybe think why ? A simple search on google can clarify this aspect. Hint ! Just review `Java Operators`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html